# convert multiple list value into string inside multilple dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list

I have data which I have shortened for the understanding.
The actual data has 100k+ dict elements inside the parent list and each individual dictionary element has 50 different key-value pairs. They are unorganized and most of the values for keys are a list. I am trying to convert those internal lists to string in an efficient way possible.

```
listOfwords = [{"test": ["This" , "is", "a", "new", "program"], "checked": "yes"}, {"checked": "no", "test": ["This" , "was", "an", "old", "program"]}, {"test": ["This", "program"], "checked": "in progress"}, {"checked": "failed", "test": []}]
```

To convert the list to string, we definitely can use `join` and I was able to do the same. But as the actual data is too large, in my consideration too much of iteration will make the code look bad. Also with join I am referencing the delimiter as `,` and that changes the complete data when it comes out

```
>>> for i in listOfwords:
...     fullStr = ' '.join(i['test'])
...     i['test'] = fullStr
...
>>> print listOfwords
[{'test': 'This is a new program', 'checked': 'yes'}, {'test': 'This was an old program', 'checked': 'no'}, {'test': 'This program', 'checked': 'in progress'}, {'test': '', 'checked': 'failed'}]
>>>
```

Expected Output

```
[{"test":"This, is, a, new, program","checked":"yes"},{"checked":"no","test":"That, was, an, old, program"},{"test":"This, program,","checked":"in progress"},{"checked":"failed","test":""}]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `fullStr = ', '.join(i['test'])` ?

Comment: Thanks that worked, also is there any way with which I can handle this for multiple lists without having iteration through the list/dict

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to change `' '.join(i['test'])` to `', '.join(i['test'])` to get what you want.

(Note the difference between `' '` and `', '` in terms of what you call `.join()` on.)

Comment: Thanks that worked, also is there any way with which I can handle this for multiple lists without having iteration through the list/dict

Comment: Iteration is the *right* and efficient way to do this - there are other ways of expressing the same concept, but they're all iterating behind the scenes. You shouldn't worry about that.